# Register PHP/SQL won't insert longtext fields

Tags: php, sql, database, insert

OK so my register system is correctly inserting into my database the username, password, and e-mail but not any other fields. I first tried putting the values directly into the SQL query and then put them in the form as hidden text fields. The direct values gave an SQL syntax error and the hidden text doesn't insert anything but successfully adds the user, pass, and email. All MYSQL field types are LONGTEXT. Here's the code.

Register.php

```
<form name="register" method="post" action="register2.php"><br />

Username<br><input name="username" type="text" size="20" /><br /><br />

Password<br><input name="password" type="password" size="20" /><br /><br />

E-mail<br><input name="email" type="text" size="20" /><br /><br />

<input="hidden" id="status" type="text" value=Waiting for a request size="100" />
<input="hidden" id="request" type="text" value="None sent" size="100" />
<input="hidden" id="paid" type="text" value="Please pay for an instant spot" size="100" />
<input="hidden" id="priority" type="text" value="To be determined by your web designer" size="100" />
<input="hidden" id="files" type="text" value="None" size="100" />
<input="hidden" id="filespass" type="text" value=None" size="100" /><div id="captcha2">
<img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" /><br><br>Please re-write the security code below<br><input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" size="20"/></div>

<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /><br><br>
<a href='forgot.php'>Forgot</a> your password?<br>

</form>
```

Register2.php

```
<?php
include_once 'securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();
if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) {
 // the code was incorrect
 // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

 // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
 echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
 echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
 exit;
 }else{

 $con = mysql_connect(secret);
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("dylanmediagroup", $con);

$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$status = htmlspecialchars($_POST['status']);
$priority = htmlspecialchars($_POST['priority']);
$paid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['paid']);
$files = htmlspecialchars($_POST['files']);
$filespass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['filespass']);

$checkuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username'");
$checkemail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$password'");

if(mysql_num_rows($checkuser) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username

echo "<img src='http://www.myhealthguardian.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/sad-face.gif' width='25%' height='21%'><br><br>Account already registered.<br> <a href='forgot.php'>Forgot</a> your password?<br><br>";

} else {

$sql="INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email, status, priority, paid, files, filespass) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$status', '$priority', '$paid', '$files', '$filespass')";

}

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {

  }else{

echo "<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vpsc13PCfc0/TaLCGaq2SjI/AAAAAAAACTA/hw2MDzTk6mg/s1600/smiley-face.jpg' height='21%' width='25%'><br><br>Your registration was successful, please <a href='login.php'>login</a> to continue.";

}
}

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Try a `var_dump($sql)` before the insert to see what the query looks like.  Also, I'd reconsider using all `LONGTEXT` types since I don't think you need all that storage for most of those columns.  Consider `VARCHAR` instead.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `htmlspecialchars` to sanitize your input. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're using id instead of name for your hidden inputs.
And please use this syntax:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
```

Also one of your values seem to break the string since it has quotation marks in it.